# Reorder Factor Variables in R

Tags: r

Thanks for the help!

I want the vector of:

`s = c(2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 1)`

to be

`s = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

I am not sorting!

Answer (score 4):

Using `rleid`

```
data.table::rleid(s)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 4):

In base R

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(s) != 0))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rle` and `inverse.rle` from the base R.

```
s <- c(2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 1)

rl <- rle(s)
rl$values <- sort(unique(s))
s <- inverse.rle(rl)

s
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 5
```